# What is the tax treatment for dividends paid on open CFD positions?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, dividends, cfd

If an investor has an open CFD position when the underlying stock goes ex-div, there will be a payment made to the margin account in lieu of dividend. This is to ensure the investor does not actually lose money when the price drops as a result of the company returning capital to investors. What is the tax treatment of this dividend payment in the UK, is it treated the same as normal stock dividends or is it capital gains?

Comment: In Australia CFDs are treated as a trading instrument, any payment from someone holding a long CFD position during an ex-div event are paid out from someone holding the opposite short position, it is not paid out by the company itself as normal share dividends are. As such it is not treated as a dividend payment at all. This could be the same in the UK.

Comment: Does that mean it's income or capital gains for tax purposes in Australia?

Comment: In Australia, profits from CFD trading are not classes as capital gains but rather income from a trading business. In the UK I think these profits are classes as capital gains (but you would need to check that). So yes the dividend payment in CFDs is simply classed as income in Australia.